# US visa about to expire - should I renew it before my next trip?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I'm an academic living in the Netherlands, originally from Palestine/Israel. In a couple of months I'll visit the US to attend an academic conference. Being an Israeli citizen, I need a visa to enter the US - and I have one, issued almost ten years ago and expiring a month after conference date; so - I can use it this time, but next time I won't have it. The visa is a B1/B2-class, type R.

My question:

- Is it possible to renew / extend / get a new visa to enter the US based on my current conference invitation, even though I already have a valid one?
- If so, is it a good idea to do this now, or should I just let my current visa expire and worry about it next time?

Comment: Wait for the next conference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no guarantee of being issued a multi entry visa it is completely pointless to ask for one when you already have one that will admit you.

B1-B2 visas can not be extended. Your stay can be extended but the visa itself can't. You will need a new one.

Type R means nothing. It means "regular". Not a diplomat, not an official, not a dog.